# Efficient creation of thread pool (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading

What is the 'best' way to create a thread pool for more efficient calculation?

Suppose I have the following code to print out how many primes are in a given interval (for demonstration only, I know it's super slow):

```cpp
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <math.h>

bool is_prime(int n) {
  if (n == 2 || n == 3) {
    return 1;
  }
  else if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  for (int i = 5; i < sqrt(n) + 1; i = i + 6) {
    if (n % i == 0 || n % (i+2) == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

int primes_in_range(int a, int b) {
  int total = 0;
  for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    total += is_prime(i);
  }
  return total;
}

int main() {

  int total = primes_in_range(2, 10000000);
  std::cout << total << std::endl;

}
```

If I want to make this run faster by splitting the interval into smaller chunks for threads, how would I do so?

Currently, I'm doing something like this:

```cpp
  auto thread1 = std::async(std::launch::async, primes_in_range, 2, 2500000);
  auto thread2 = std::async(std::launch::async, primes_in_range, 2500001, 5000000);
  auto thread3 = std::async(std::launch::async, primes_in_range, 5000001, 7500000);
  auto thread4 = std::async(std::launch::async, primes_in_range, 7500001, 10000000);
  int total1 = thread1.get();
  int total2 = thread2.get();
  int total3 = thread3.get();
  int total4 = thread4.get();
  std::cout << total1 + total2 + total3 + total4 << std::endl;
```

But this doesn't seem very efficient, especially if I try to have say `n` threads.

What is a better way to do it? I'm fairly new to multithreading in general, so do tell me if I am doing something terribly wrong!

Comment: why do you think this isnt efficient? Because of the amount of code to write? You can use a container of threads and loops to create and join them

Comment: `std::asynch` does not return a thread. It returns a `std::future`

Comment: btw my first comment was misled by variable names, but you can use a vector of futures as well, use loops to create them and to get their result.

Comment: do you mean "efficient" in terms of execution time or in terms of writing the code?

Comment: I mean "efficient" in terms of writing the code that scales to any number of threads, but the execution time should be optimal

Comment: I tried `std::vector<std::future<int>> threads;` then `threads.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, primes_in_range, i/num_threads * a, (i+1)/num_threads * a));` and then `total += threads[i].get();` in separate for loops, but that resulted in code that had the same execution time as single threading it.

Comment: i guess you called `push_back` and `get` within the same loop. You need to first push all the futures and only then call their `get`

Comment: If you are on Windows, std::async already uses a threadpool (not so under linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider you would calculate the results for the intervals sequentially. Then you would use loops and you can do the same with `std::asynch` and `std::future` (`std::asynch` does not return a thread).

```
auto get_future_chunk(int from, int to){
    return std::async(std::launch::async, primes_in_range, from,to);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<decltype(get_future_chunk(0,0))> futures;
    int from = 2;
    int chunk_size = 5000000;
    const int max = 10000000;    
    int to = from+chunk_size;
    while (to <= max) {
        futures.push_back(get_future_chunk(from,to));
        from = to + 1;
        to += chunk_size;        
    }
    futures.push_back(get_future_chunk(from,max));
    int total = 0;
    for (auto& f : futures) total += f.get();
    std::cout << total << "\n";
}
```

The only reason I wrote the function is because I was too lazy to look up the exact type of the future returned from `asynch` and with the help of the function I can deduce it more easily. For testing on godbolt I used only two chunks because when requesting lots of threads I got an error for unavailable resource. The code fixes the `chunk_size` and based on that determines the number of futures to be spawned. The reverse is of course possible as well: Fix the number of chunks and then calculate the interval bounds.

[Complete example](https://godbolt.org/z/caszzeo1Y)

Comment: You could also deduce the type using [std::invoke_result](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) ;)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to simply use OpenMP which is supported by all mainstream C++ compilers so far (eg. GCC, Clang, ICC, and even MSVC though there are some quicks). You just need to compile your code with `-fopenmp` and use a `#pragma omp parallel reduction(+:total)` directive and OpenMP will create a thread pool, compute the operation in parallel and perform the synchronizations. It also recycle the thread pool so to create it only once (unless you change the number of threads or things like this). Here is an example:

```cpp
int primes_in_range(int a, int b) {
  int total = 0;
  #pragma omp parallel reduction(+:total)
  for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    total += is_prime(i);
  }
  return total;
}
```

OpenMP enable you to tweak the scheduling which is useful here since `is_prime` takes a variable amount of time so a load balancing can result in better performance (a `schedule(guided)` clause should result in faster performance but it is better to simply test the available schedule). If you need to defer computation, you can use OpenMP tasking primitives which are also pretty simple to use (and it avoids to re-implement the wheel yet another time by letting the OpenMP runtime does all the hard/boring/bug-prone work for you).